# Find biggest repetitions of size n and less in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of elements like so:

```
['x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i']
```

I would like to find all the "biggest" repetitions of `n` elements and below and the number of times each sequence is repeated. For example, if `n=3`:

```
>>> [(['a', 'b', 'c'], 3), (['g', 'h'], 2), (['i'], 4)]
```

I also don't want to return `(['i', 'i'], 2)` since there is a longer sequence involving the element `'i'`.

Here is a second condition:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i']
>>> [(['a', 'b', 'c'], 3), (['b', 'c'], 2), (['g', 'h'], 2), (['i'], 4)]
```

Overlapping of elements belonging to 2 different repetitions are accepted.

I was thinking about a solution based on sliding windows of size `n` and decreasing, keeping track of the already used indices but I doesn't fulfill the first condition.

Is there an efficient way of doing so?

Comment: Do the repetitions have to appear consecutively ?

Comment: I think there is a flaw in your logic -- sequences of length 1 will always be equal to or longer than larger sequences that contain them. If you have `3 ['a','b','c']`, you are guaranteed to have at least `3 ['a']`

Comment: They have to be consecutive.

Comment: That makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function:

```
import re
def counting(x):
    d = re.sub(r"(?<=(\w))(?=\1)","\n","\n".join(re.findall(r"(\w+)(?=\1)",''.join(x)))).split()
    return  [(list(i),d.count(i)+1)for i in set(d)]
```

Now you can run this function on your data:

```
m = ['x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i']

counting(m)
[(['g', 'h'], 2), (['i'], 4), (['a', 'b', 'c'], 3)]


n = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i']

counting(n)
[(['g', 'h'], 2), (['i'], 4), (['a', 'b', 'c'], 3), (['b', 'c'], 2)]
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected, as it counts non consecutive repetitions. With `seq = 'aabbaa'`, it returns `[(['a'], 3), (['b'], 2)]` instead of `[(['a'], 2), (['b'], 2)]`

Comment: Yes, the OP made clear in the comments that repetitions have to be consecutive. And there is no consecutive sequence of 3 `a`, only sequences of 2.

Comment: The problem is that each sequence must have a unique key.. ie like in the example we have `abc, bc` etc and we are counting this. Now in your case you have `aa` then `bb` then `aa` again!! so this is not a unique key!!! it will just be added on top of the previous `aa` -1

Comment: @ThierryLathuille let me help you what answer would you expect from `aaaabbbbaaabbbaabb`????

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
>>> li=['x', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i']
>>> [(t[0],''.join(t).count(t[0])) for t in re.findall(r'(\w+)(\1+)', ''.join(li))]
[('abc', 3), ('gh', 2), ('ii', 2)]
```

Or,

```
>>> [(list(t[0]),''.join(t).count(t[0])) for t in re.findall(r'(\w+)(\1+)', ''.join(li))
[(['a', 'b', 'c'], 3), (['g', 'h'], 2), (['i', 'i'], 2)]
```

Comment: It doesn't handle the first condition I mentioned but I feel like I can add a function that will filter out the ('xxx') element and handle the `(['x'], n)` corner case after.

Comment: How would you modify your solutions to handle elements of size > 1, like `"xyz"`?

Comment: Since the list is joined into a single string without distinction, multi character elements would jut become part of the total string. So if you replaced `'b'` entirely with `'xyz'` you would get the result of `[('axyzc', 3), ('gh', 2), ('ii', 2)]`

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I wonder how I could modify your solutions to undle multi characters elements.

Comment: What does 'handle' mean in this case? You need to be specific of input and desired output.